# Do ultrasonic motion detectors (like the Arduino sensor) detect small particles like dust when receiving waves? If they don't why is that the case?

Tags: waves, frequency, radio

This may be a bit of an elementary question but I've recently started studying physics for fun so this has confused me. Do ultrasonic sensors have the capability to detect very small particles like dust, or is there some limit to the size of the objects that the waves can bounce off of? I assume that if the area was void of other objects, the sensor could pick up the particles of dust since the waves would rebound off of the particles from the transmitter into the receiver. I know this falls in the area of electrical engineering I'm pretty sure, so sorry if its not fully physics.

Answer (score 1):

Waves of any kind tend not to interact with particles or obstacles that are much smaller than their wavelength. I don't know the frequency/wavelength of "the Arduino sensor," But let's just guess that it's 40kHz. That is a commonly used frequency for open-air ultrasonic applications. At 40kHz, under standard conditions, the wavelength in air would be roughly eight millimeters.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. thank you.